# Why is this str.format causing a Key Error in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

I have the following code in a python 2.7.10 script

```
params = {'F': '250', 'I': '-22.5', 'J': '-22.5', 'Y': '12.817175976', 'X': '7.4', 'Z': '-50'}
G3 = 'G3 F {F} I {I} J {J} X {X} Y {Y} Z {Z}  \n'
print(params)
print(G3)
print(G3.format(params))
```

When I try to run it it gives the following output:

```
./g-codeGenerator.py
{'F': '250', 'I': '-22.5', 'J': '-22.5', 'Y': '12.817175976', 'X': '7.4', 'Z': '-50'}
G3 F {F} I {I} J {J} X {X} Y {Y} Z {Z} 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  **Traceback truncated**
  File "./g-codeGenerator.py", line 342, in siliconOutputSequence
    print(G3.format(params))
KeyError: 'F'
```

Why is this causing the key error, as far as I can see all of the required elements are present in the parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `.format()` is not expecting a dictionary; it's expecting keyword arguments.  `.format({'F': 4})` should be changed to `.format(F=4)`.  To do that with your dictionary, use `**`:

```
print(G3.format(**params))
```

For more information on argument unpacking, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: *facepalm* Thanks, I feel like a real idiot now looking about 4 lines above my code snippet and seeing exactly that where it's working properly.

Comment: Don't worry.  It took me a minute to see your problem ;)

Answer (score 4):

You just need to unpack the dictionary into the format string using the `**` operator:

```
print(G3.format(**params))
```

**Output**

```
G3 F 250 I -22.5 J -22.5 X 7.4 Y 12.817175976 Z -50
```